# Alternative audio source

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones, speakers

I recently moved, and after setting up my computer again, I found that I couldn't get audio through the main audio jack ports. I have a Dell XPS 8900, which has an integrated 7.1 channel Realtek ALC3861 High Definition Audio with Waves MaxxAudio Pro. I have a TaoTronics soundbar, which just has a single audio and microphone plug. I did upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS before the move, but that had no effect. I tried plugging into the headphone jack on the top of the PC, and my sound was back, albeit with kind of an annoying plugin spot. Fast forward a few weeks, and out of nowhere while watching a YouTube video, the speaker started sounding really staticky so I unplugged it from the headphone jack, and plugged it back in and it is back to no sound at all from any port. I've tried the speaker in another computer and it works fine. I've also done a bunch of diagnostics using speaker-test, etc, and I believe it has nothing to do with my modules, ALSA, PulseAudio, or my speaker. I am able to get audio through Bluetooth headphones, but after some time, that seemed to be causing problems with wifi. Finally, this brings me to my questions:

First, has anyone experienced this, and if so, how did you resolve it?

Second, what are my alternatives? I can replace the sound card, but that is kind of a last resort. I'd prefer a simpler solution. Are there speakers that work with HDMI? Or possibly over Wifi? If so, what would you recommend?

Comment: I'm dual booting Ubuntu 18.04 and Ubuntu 22.04. My Creative Pebble v3 (connected via USB) works in Ubuntu 22.04 out of the box, but *not* in Ubuntu 18.04. However, I can get sound in both cases through the main audio ports. I don't have a solution but maybe you could get Live CDs with both Ubuntu 18.04 and the latest Ubuntu 22.04 and see if your speaker system works; it could be the upgrade messed something up. (In my case, Ubuntu 18.04 was upgraded from 16.04 but the 22.04 is a fresh installation.)

Answer (score 0):

I realize this isn't a great question, and may not really be suited for this forum. I also asked over in [Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) and my question was removed as off-topic.  However, I did find an acceptable solution to my problem. I took a gamble on some Creative Pebble V3 USB-C Desktop Speakers. Around $40, they came with a USB C-A adapter, and I simply plugged them in and they worked. I am still unsure of what caused the analog ports to stop working, but for my purposes, this solution is as good as any.